# Lotus Notes web form not updating

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a web form we use in Lotus Notes, it is an ASP page loaded off of the server into the Notes calendar.  It is loaded using the embedded browser into a Form.  We update some fields on it, then use the data off of it to send as an email.

Whenever some of the form fields are updated they are present for the duration of the form but, not when the form is re-opened.  If I update the form and send an email, it is fine.  If I then close the form and re-open it the values are lost. Closing Notes and re-opening it before loading the form will show the correct updated form values.  Is there any reason why it is not displaying the updates without restarting the application?

**Update**:  I've tried just changing the HTML on the page to verify it was not a cache issue and changing HTML on the page works.  The data I am using to update the fields is coming from hidden fields and it looks like those are not updating correctly...if that helps any.  They do update correctly on the ASP page in other locations (Outlook, IE/Firefox, etc).

**Another Update**: It is a problem with a hidden field being set.  I have a field being set as such:

```
<input type="hidden" id="IntList" name="IntList" value="<%=data.AttList%>">
```

When I load the data the first time, it is blank as it should be.  Putting a value into that field works, the first time only.  Re-opening the form will show the newly added data.  Adding data to the field again will show (user2 is the newly added user):

```
<input type="hidden" id="IntList" name="IntList" value="user1|user2">
```

After closing the form it flips back to (user1 was the initial add):

```
<input type="hidden" id="IntList" name="IntList" value="user1">
```

Closing Notes and re-opening it and the field now becomes correct:

```
<input type="hidden" id="IntList" name="IntList" value="user1|user2">
```

Comment: You need to add more detail about what you're doing. You're opening an ASP from within your Notes app? How are you rendering it? Via the embedded browser in a Notes form? If you update fields in the page and these updates "disappear", surely you need to look at what serialisation (if any) is happening in the ASP application?

Comment: The ASP application is working correctly, if it weren't the correct data should not be there when I restart Notes I would not think.  Browsing to the site itself works, and the databases are all in the correct states.  Also the same form loaded into an Outlook application works correctly.  I am loading an ASP page into the embedded browser in a Notes form, adding that to the problem.

Comment: Hard to diagnose based on this. But it sounds to me as if the ASP app wants to set some cookies or similar, and the embedded browser isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to make it easier to diagnose?   It is a Notes app that loads an ASP page into the browser in a Form on the calendar view.   I'm admittedly not a Notes person, I'm just working on the task because there is no one else to do it so anything I can add just ask.  Thanks for your input thus far too.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a hidden form field not updating correctly on this I think.

Comment: FWIW, the embedded browser in Notes is IE (I know, I know…) so there could be something funky going on with IE's "security" (the whole internet / intranet settings thing). More than that I can't really advise I'm afraid: embedded browser stuff isn't well-documented in Notes.

Comment: IE...hmm... I've updated it again.  It's really odd what I'm seeing and it's only in Notes it is behaving this way.  It's almost like the server side call is cached or something that it is showing an old version unless I restart it.

Comment: Aye ca rumba, the ASP page didn't implement no-cache. Putting that in works...If you put your comments into an answer I will accept it since you helped me out greatly in this.

Comment: Much appreciated; glad this worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the embedded browser in Notes is IE (I know, I know…) so there could be something funky going on with IE's "security" (the whole internet / intranet settings thing). More than that I can't really advise I'm afraid: embedded browser stuff isn't well-documented in Notes.

Glad you got this sorted out!